# Weird adware source code in every website

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, internet-explorer, adware

I've got a weird script popping up on *every* website I go on. What makes it even *weirder* is that it does absolutely nothing. I didn't notice anything until I saw this kind of stuff:

[image]

I've tried making it bigger and visible but the iframe is transparent. There is nothing there. How can I get rid of this? I am not running any suspicious extensions and I've run Chrome Suspicious Software Remover, or whatever it's called. I've run multiple scans with my Antivirus AND MalwareBytes. Still nothing.

Is this dangerous? What does it do? How do I get rid of it? Thanks in advance.

This issue exists in both IE and Chrome

EDIT: It is gone! It was a program called "SuperFish Inc Visual Discovery" installed. I have deleted it and uninstalled it completely and now my browsers are best-deals-products free!

Comment: Do you know how to change/check your system proxy settings? If MBAM isn't catching it then I'd guess that your web traffic is being ran through an ad proxy server that another application setup under your internet settings.

Comment: How do I check my system proxy settings?

Comment: Open the control panel and search for `Internet Options`. Open that, then switch to the `Connections` tab and click `LAN Settings`. You should see a checkbox next to some text that starts off with `Use a proxy server...`. If it's checked, uncheck it and see if that removes the ads. Let us know if that solves the problem or not.

Comment: It wasn't checked. I checked it and opened internet and unchecked it just to see if it would do anything but no.

Comment: If you download and install Firefox, does the code snippet still show up in that browser? Also, in Gogole Chrome's installed extensions page, do you see any add-ons that you don't recognize?

Comment: No, all of the extensions I recognize, and I've disabled them all and checked and it still showed up. As for Firefox, yes, it does show up. I just downloaded and checked.

Comment: If you look at the page source for [google.com](http://www.google.com) is the ad-code present? Additionally, if you look at the source for the same page but [accessing it via IP](http://74.125.28.138) rather than domain name, does the code show up?

Comment: @int_541 Nope, code isn't there. But on the IP site it is

edit: Reloaded page and now it isn't there on the IP site...

Comment: @int_541 here's a gif of what's happening http://i.imgur.com/ndVwGxx.gif on this gif i go on Google, Reddit, Youtube, and Netflix. Strangely enough this best-deals-products source only appears on Reddit and Netflix. I assure you that the source would happen on Google before, and also Youtube (because I've checked in the past).

Comment: Woo! See my edit.

Comment: Your edit should really be an answer describing what you did to remove it.